# How can I cancel a [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

Tags: objective-c, avaudiosession, audiosession

Currently I have an audio session where I use

`audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];`

to override the ringer but I would like to know if there is a way that I can undo this so that my audio session will not be a shared instance.

Comment: not clear what are you asking.. :(

Answer (score 0):

No.  An iOS app's audio session is automatically shared by the OS, the manner of sharing depending on the audio session category that your app configures, and the state of the app (foreground or background, etc.).  Incoming phone calls (etc.) can interrupt and override your app's session.